# Ajax in asp.net - generic handlers or webservices?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

Are there any pros and cons between them both? Which is better to use for example with jquery ajax calls? I think webservices are somewhat bloated.. or can anyone convince me of the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

I have used .asmx, .ashx and .aspx files (add Theme="" to the Page declaration to not include master pages) for Ajax Web services and noticed no difference. I think having all sorts of different file extensions in ASP.NET may have been a mistake.